# Make Relative layout of Alert dialog fits center

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I created a Relative Layout for my Alert Dialog, but when I execute the app, this is what I see:
[image]

How can I modify it to fit the center of the screen? I think I also need to resize the are because it too big, can this be the problem? This is the code

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/myCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Abilitare la palette di colori?" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Inserisci l'eta'">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myCheckBox"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/maleRadioButton">


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Maschio" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/maleRadioButton"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Femmina" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add android:gravity="center" in relative layout. This may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android:gravity="center"

You add one to your main relative layout.

```
 <RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/myCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Abilitare la palette di colori?" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Inserisci l'eta'">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myCheckBox"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/maleRadioButton">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Maschio" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/maleRadioButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Femmina" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```